# remove html page style tag

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm trying to remove the HTML style tag and all of the content between so the page has no styling I cant seem to get it to work

This is what I have

```
$PageContent = qq~<style type="text/css">
/* PAGE STYLE */
body {
      margin:24px;
      padding:0px;
      background:#323232;
      color:#EEEEEE;
      min-width:748px;
      font-family:'Verdana', sans-serif;
      font-size:9pt;
      font-weight:500;
      line-height:12pt;
      text-decoration: none;
}</style>~;

$PageContent =~ s/<style.*?<\/style>//isg;

print $PageContent;
```

Comment: One problem with your code is that sometimes styles are nested. Tags of the form `<style>...<style>...</style>...<style>...</style></style>` will make this fail.

Comment: When I run your code, it perfectly works. It removes everything between (and including) `<style>` and `</style>`. The result is an empty string. Please show a _"[Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)"_ of your code. Show an example where your attempt failed.

Comment: ***Please don't ever try to edit HTML using regular expressions***.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an HTML DOM Parser like [Mojo::DOM](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/DOM).

```
use Mojo::DOM;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new;
my $html = "<div><div><div>Test</div></div></div>";

while($html =~ m/<div>/) {
   $html = $dom->parse($html)->at('div')->strip;
}

print $html;

Output: Test
```

Also use one of the DOM functions to match `<div>` tags. The line with `$html =~ m/div/` in my example, is just for simple demonstration purpose.